# mongo db using fields that begin with numeric values

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a project that uses mongo db. I am trying to do a comparison between two fields, 2016rank and 2015rank, respectively. I would like it to return the results where the 2016 rank has improved over the 2015 rank.

This is what I wrote to do it.

```
db.Car_Dealership.find( {$where : function() {return this.2016rank > this.2015rank}});
```

I receive an error when I do this. "identifier starts immediately after numeric literal" and I know exactly why. It is because my rank fields begin with numerical values. Is the only solution to rename the fields?

Comment: Checkout [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) in the upcoming release.  That would allow you to do `db.Car_Dealership.find({ $expr: { $gt: [ "$2016ran" , "$2015rank" ] } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using bracket notation instead of dot notation:

```
db.Car_Dealership.find( {$where : function() {return this["2016rank"] > this["2015rank"]}});
```